# Let $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ are two bounded sequence. I need to prove $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}|X_{n}-Y_{n}|=0$ iff $X_{n}=Y_{n}$ for all $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ are two bounded sequence. I need to prove $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}|X_{n}-Y_{n}|=0$ iff $X_{n}=Y_{n}$ for all $n$.

I want this proof. Because if you see this in metric space then this is come from $l_{\infty}$ metric space. First of all if $ X_{n}=Y_{n}$ then the condition holds. But difficulty arise for reverse case. I first suppose if $X_{n} \neq Y_{n}$ and we have $\sup_{n\in \mathbb N}|X_{n}-Y_{n}|=0$. There exist atleast one $n$ for which $X_{n}\neq Y_{n}$ for this $n$, $\sup_{n\in \mathbb N}|X_{n}-Y_{n}| > 0$ then here is a contradiction. I now prove this way. Is there any property of Supremum for which I say directly?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Thank you for your edit this is way better (but a bit confused I have to say). FYI, users asking questions are expected to show their effort.

Comment: Here I use the method to proof this statement is very long so is there any property so I directly used to proof the statement in few lines

Comment: I do not get why people are still downvoting your question. It seems fine to me now. And I think you have proven what you want (execpt you have $>0$ and not $\ge 0$ but this is a direct property of the sup to be greater or equal to one of its element.

Comment: Yeah, I'm voting to reopen. Anyway the important property of $\sup$ here is as follows: $\sup(A)\geq a$ for any $a\in A$. Therefore if $X\neq Y$, then $X_m\neq Y_m$ for some $m$, which is equivalent to $|X_m-Y_m|>0$, which by the property mentioned before implies $\sup_{n} |X_n-Y_n|\geq |X_m-Y_m|>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more direct argument would be that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$,

$$0\leq\lvert X_n-Y_n\rvert\leq\sup_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\lvert X_m-Y_m\rvert=0,$$

so $\lvert X_n-Y_n\rvert=0$, i.e. $X_n=Y_n$.